# scrollTop is giving me cross-browser issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

Below is my JavaScript for detecting if I am at the end of a page, but it is fired twice when I am running it in internet explorer or safari, while the same script is working fine in firefox and chrome. I am not able to figure it out where it might have went wrong?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){ 
         somefunctionCall();
     } 
});
```

Comment: Looks like you forget to post code

Comment: *"The above query"* ? Which one ?

Comment: $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                    functionCall();
                }
});

Comment: I am using jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Comment: @Vicky add that to your post

Comment: It's supposed to fire multiple times while you scroll. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: and what it is showing you in the console?

Comment: Have you seen what values $(window).scrollTop() and $(window).height() return?  Perhaps they are not returning the same values in all browsers, in which case you probably want to look into how they work.

Comment: @bfavaretto no if fires multiple time when it reaches at the bottom of the page. It must fire once when i am at the bottom, again it should fire if i have scrolled again.

Comment: @MichaelUnterthurner it is showing nothing.

Comment: Maybe `$(document).ready(function{});` around your code?

Comment: @Bondye i dont think this will work, as document is ready. then only i am able to run the above script.

Comment: Huh?! `then only i am able to run the above script` I guess you don't understand jQuery. Your code does work when using [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) http://jsfiddle.net/t5JK6/

Answer (score 1):

In Internet explorer the scroll event can be fired multiple times when scrolling.
You can use debounce (underscoreJs or jQuery) to make sure the event isn't fired too often.

Example:

```
$(window).scroll(jQuery.debounce(100, function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){ 
         functionCall(); 
     } 
}));
```

Comment: what for debounce is used, i m not getting clear picture of this function after googling.

Comment: It ensures the code is not called multiple times within the interval specified (100 milliseconds in my example).

Comment: i wanted to fire the above script instantly as i reached at the bottom of the page.

Comment: again, did not work? no call to your code, or multiple times?

Comment: i want to call the  functionCall(); only once when i am at the bottom of page, the above script runs fine when i am using it on firefox, but their is issue in internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It is discouraged to use the scroll events. See: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: then what is the alternate. I wanted to call some function as soon as i reached at the bottom of the page.

Comment: use setTimeout and get $(window).scrollTop() in the callback